Salesforce Employee Service - My Support Ticket List component is not working (work.com)
I added the Salesforce provided component My Support Ticket List in Employee service Site.  I am the admin user, I have access to case object. It throws error that "We couldnt find that page. Check the URL and try again". Case is private access for external user.
Appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Lakshmi
